# Cmputer not following rules

Tags: java

I'm trying to come up with a reverse guessing game. Computer to guess my selected number with a range of 1-100. I do have the binary search algorithm, but when I tell the computer it's first guess is Too High, it will give me another High guess instead of going lower.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputersGuessGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random value = new Random();

    int computerGuess;
    int highValue = 100;
    int lowValue = 1;
    String myAnswer;

    do {
        computerGuess = value.nextInt(highValue - lowValue +1)/2;

        /*
         *Above line should use the binary algorithm so the computer can
         *make guesses and not just guess my number by going one number at a time
        */

        System.out.println("I'm guessing that your number is " + computerGuess);
        myAnswer = in.nextLine();


        if (myAnswer.equals("tl")){
            highValue = computerGuess + 1;//Too Low Answer
        }
        else if (myAnswer.equals ("th")){
            lowValue = computerGuess - 1;//To High Answer
        }
    } while (!myAnswer.equals("y")); //Answer is correct

    in.close();
    System.out.println("Thank you, Good Game.");


        }
}//Comptuer keeps making random guesses, but if I say too high, it will guess another high number instead of going low.
```

Comment: If I choose 20 and the computer guessed 90. Then it is too high. Then the `lowValue` will be 89. meaning the next random number generated will be in the range (1,6)... seems rightish

Comment: Can you give a full example of input/output?

Comment: I am still searching for Binary Search. Did somone find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic to guess the next number was wrong. You should have interchange the setting the lower & high value,and change the logic to generate next guess.

here is the working solution of your problem

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random value = new Random();
        int computerGuess;
        int highValue = 100;
        int lowValue = 1;
        String myAnswer;
        do {
            computerGuess = value.nextInt(highValue - lowValue)+lowValue;
            System.out.println("I'm guessing that your number is " + computerGuess);
            myAnswer = in.nextLine();
            if (myAnswer.equals("tl")){
                lowValue = computerGuess + 1;
            } else if (myAnswer.equals ("th")){
                highValue = computerGuess - 1;
            }
        } while (!myAnswer.equals("y"));
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Thank you, Good Game.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back Taj

Answer (score 0):

you should try to approximate to your guess. you should try nested intervals. your working with class random, of course your computer could guess another high number again, when only lowering the range by one.

you should work with at least 2 new variables, rangeLow and rangeHigh. when to high, your new rangeHigh is your last guess. when to low, your new rangeLow is your last guess.

computerGuess = value.nextInt(rangeLow,rangeHigh);

Comment: Thanks bloodscript and Taj Ahmed for your feedback. It's funny and frustrating when just one little character is out of place that makes the difference. A second pair of eyes was exactly what I needed.